# Behance API Endpoint for Team?

Tags: api, adobe, endpoint, behance-api

**A simple quesition :**

I was wondering there is possible to get **projects by team** ? *(like getting projects on users)*

```
https://www.behance.net/v2/users/{name}/projects?api_key={key}
```

I tried to insert my **team name**, So it does not work.

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this hack. Add all your teams projects to a collection. You can now access relevant data from the collections end-point

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to retrieve projects by team as of now. The users endpoint is to get the projects published by a user